# Vertical align in table on Latex

Tags: latex, multicol

I want to make a table and print the text in the middle of all cases. I use the array package and I wrote:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|m{3cm}|m{2.5cm}|m{2.5cm}|m{2.5cm}|m{6cm}|}
```

But then Latex says that I missed one '$' or one '{' in my table... but there is only text, so I don't understand. When I switched to :

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|m{3cm}|C{2.5cm}|C{2.5cm}|C{2.5cm}|C{6cm}|}
```

all is ok and works... but it's ugly. I read a lot of stuff about that on the site already but never fixed my obvious-like problem :/

Comment: [Duplicate of another question on StackExchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7208/how-to-vertically-center-the-text-of-the-cells)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a minimal example of the layout I use for tables. 
Different combinations of sizing and formatting are shown.
I am not sure if this is what you asked for. Please reformulate your question, if it is not.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{booktabs} % \cmidrule in tables
% \usepackage{caption}  % Nice Captions
% \usepackage{longtable} % Tables larger than one page
% \usepackage{multirow} % Mergings Cells
% \usepackage{multicol} % Merging Cells
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \caption{Some caption, for tables always above}
  \label{some label}
  \begin{tabularx}{0.99\textwidth}{>{\centering}X>{\raggedleft}X>{\raggedleft}X>{\raggedleft}p{0.5cm}>{\raggedleft}p{3cm}>{\raggedright}X>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
    \toprule
    \textsc{Foobar} & $a$ & $b$ & $c$ & $d$ & $e$ & $f$ \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-6} \cmidrule(l){7-7}
    1               & 2   & 2   & 2   & 2   & 2   & 2   \\
    2               & 4   & 5   & 4   & 4   & 4   & 4   \\
    3               & 4   & 3   & 4   & 3   & 3   & 3   \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: PDF]